# Use Font Awesome with "background: url" css

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have a dream !

This 'star' is generated with Font Awesome.

[star1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wywd2.jpg)

I wan't to replace the green color with an image like this :

[star2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keGIM.jpg)

This is a Fiddle with what i have try:
http://jsfiddle.net/jmcpeak/M6N24

```
  background: url(https://paperpackagingplace.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/yellow-2.jpg) -100px -40px no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

Do know how i can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked [This Article](https://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/).

Also, in this case the `i` elements work a little differently. In the `i` elements the text is used in the `content` definition for the `::before` element. You could play with that definition specifically.  You can use the following example, you just have to play with the background positioning and size.

```css
.fa-star {
   font-size: 5rem !important;
}

.fa-star::before {
   color: white;
   background: url(https://ktfnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/World-512x360.jpg) no-repeat left center;
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="fa fa-star"></i>
```

What you could do otherwise is copy the character from [FontAwesome 4.7's cheatsheet](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/cheatsheet/) as text and just make a class that uses FontAwesome as a font. Something like this (the square in the `h1` element is a copied icon from the cheatsheet, it appears like that since it's not a standard character:

```css
.awesome {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 10rem;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(https://ktfnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/World-512x360.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h1 class="awesome"></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much and sorry for have link bad Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which icon you want to change, you just need to target specific class or all `i` elements.

```css
.fa-star:before {
  background: url(https://ktfnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/World-512x360.jpg) -100px -40px no-repeat;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much and sorry for have link bad Fiddle